# Find if any of the element of an array present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

In my javascript code, I have the following two arrays,

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];
```

I want to know if any of the element of `arr2` present in `arr1`. In the above case, it is present.

Yes, it can be easily found by iterating over. But I am looking for a simpler way. If there are any lodash function, that will also be useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: What can be simpler then `arr2.every(el => arr1.indexOf(el) > -1)` ?

Comment: @dfsq you mean `some`

Comment: @mathiasfk I was answering for *`every of the element`*, missread. In case of *`any of the element`* one would use `some` of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check it with [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method combined with [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];

console.log( arr2.every(el => arr1.indexOf(el) > -1) )
```

UPD. Correction: I read the question as *"if every of the elements"* for which above answer will do. In case of *"if any of the elements"* you need to use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `every`:

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];

console.log( arr2.some(el => arr1.indexOf(el) > -1) )
```

Comment: EUh, isn't some better? This check if every element in arr2 is inside arr1. We want 'true' if any element is in arr1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `some` that will return `true/false` and `intersection` that will find same elements in both arrays.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];

var result = _.some(_.intersection(arr1, arr2))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With plain js you can also just use `some` and `includes`

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];

var result = arr1.some(e => arr2.includes(e))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use _.intersection from docs [here](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection)

intersection returns you the elements both array has

```
 var d = _.intersection(arr1, arr2);
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/3897/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the common elements on intersection variable.

```
var intersection = $.grep(arr1 , function(element) {
    return $.inArray(element, arr2) !== -1;
});

console.log(intersection);
```